# Merge SWT images

Tags: java, image, swt

I need to merge/combine two SWT images in Java.

Unfortunately I am having issue with the result image coloring, and the result image does not have transparency like the original two images.

I am not an image expert, but I think the PaletteData of the result ImageData somehow affects the coloring for copied pixels of copied second image and the transparency.

```
ImageData targetData = new ImageData(sourceData1.width + sourceData2.width,
sourceData1.height, sourceData1.depth, sourceData1.palette);
```

Changing  SourceData1.palette to  SourceData2.palette would affects coloring for the copied pixels of first image.

The full code can be found in : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=153863

I tried to change  the PaletteData for the targetData before coping the pixels of the
second image, but that did not work also.

```
merge(sourceData1, targetData, sourceData1.x, sourceData1.x, 1);
targetData.palette = sourceData2.palette;
merge(sourceData2, targetData, startX, startY, 1);
```

Tried also to copy the Alpha for each pixel but that did not work as well :

```
targetData.setAlpha(startX + i, startY + j, sourceData.getAlpha(i, j));
targetData.setPixel(startX + i, startY + j, sourceData.getPixel(i, j));
```

Here a sample of two SWT images and the result one:

First SWT Image  ( size 16x16 , gif format)

[image]

Second SWT Image  (size 8x16 , gif format)

[image]

result SWT image: (size 24x16, gif format)

[image]

Note:

- Although both images have transparency, the result image doesn't.
- I tried to convert the targetData to SWT image instead of saving into file, and the result was the same.

```
Image resultSWTImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), targetData);
```

Comment: The JFace `CompositeImageDescriptor` has code to merge images.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, I did not use this class.   
I found it easier to use     OverlayIcon class.

Answer (score 1):

As the purpose of merging was for icon decoration.
I was able to perform the merging using this code :

```
    OverlayIcon resultIcon = new OverlayIcon(BaseIconDescriptor, iconDecorationDescriptor, new Point(16, 16));   
    swt.graphics.Image icon = resultIcon.createImage();
```

Comment: I would leave this question open, as my founding does not really resolve the Image merging problems (Colors and Transparency), and I do not want to give false impression that I solved the problem described above